# exception in service container in symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, service

I have problem with service container in Symfony 5.
I have basic class CoreModel and I want use it in base controller, that everyone has access to it.

```
namespace App\Model;

use App\Model\Core\CodeModel;

class CounterModel
{

}
```

My call in controller:

```
$this->get('model.counter');
```

I added to services.yml this connection

```
services:
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Utils,Service,Model,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Form, Validatior, Kernel.php}'

    model.counter:
        class: App\Model\CounterModel
```

and i have all the time error.

```
Service "model.counter" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\CountersController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "message_bus", "messenger.default_bus", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.
```

I have no idea what to do wrong. Adding CounterModel in constructor controller is ok. But I don't care about such a solution.

Comment: fetching services from the container is not good style. however: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services

Comment: Are you upgrading from Symfony 2 legacy apps?  Things have changed quite a bit.  If you insist on being able to pull your service from the container then read up on service locators and examine the AbstractController's source code to see how to add your service to it's locator.  But it would really would be best to follow the documented recommended practices.

Comment: @jakumi yes, i tried add public to my service but it didn't help.

Comment: Inject (using typehint) directly that service in controller's constructor (or action, if that service isn't "controller wide").

Answer (score 1):

try to make your service `model.counter` public:

```
services:
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Utils,Service,Model,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Form, Validatior, Kernel.php}'

    model.counter:
        class: App\Model\CounterModel
        public: true # <--- here
```